# Can the value of final static field change in android?

Tags: android

I'm working on `SharedPreferences` and in my program i have a final static variable each for name and email as

```
 public static final String PREF_NAME = "name";
 public static final String PREF_EMAIL = "email";
```

After initializing my `SharedPreferences` Object,

```
  SharedPreferences sPref = this.getSharedPreferences("com.vivid.sharedprefrences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I Change the value of the constant fields by replacing them by the user entered name and email

```
 sEditor.putString(PREF_NAME,name);
    sEditor.putString(PREF_EMAIL,email);
    sEditor.commit();
```

But as per the other answers on stack overflow `a static final variable value cannot be changed once initialized`
But here the value of a static final field changes when i insert the name and email into `PREF_NAME` and `PREF_EMAIL`
How is that possible?

Comment: It's preference Name not value.

Comment: No same as java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this `sEditor.putString(PREF_EMAIL,email);`, the first parameter is the key and not the value. So what happens is in your preference the value of email is saved for the KEY `PREF_EMAIL`.

Hence the key is never changing. Your shared preference are `Key-ValuePair` kind of collections. The value of String `PREF_EMAIL` is what you have defined in the line - `public static final String PREF_EMAIL = "email";` i.e. **email** and will always remain the same.

The value of preference saved with the identifier key as `PREF_EMAIL` changes.

so your Shared Preference will be saved as -

`email = "email@sample.com"` // this is just an example representation.

Answer (score 0):

its a sharedPrefence key so basically you are changing the value against the key not the static final variable

Answer (score 0):

Use this two function to **set** and **get** value of your name & email

```
private static String SHARED_PREFERENCE ="your.package.name";

public static void setNameValue(Context c, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sp = c.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("name", value);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getNameValue(Context c) {
    SharedPreferences sp = c.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCE, 0);
    return sp.getString("name", "");
}
```

then just call those function `demo.setNameValue(context,"your_name_from_edittext");`

You can do same for **email** and other fields